# jQuery: Declare a Variable Using Dynamic Content

Tags: jquery, variables

I'm trying to figure out how to create a variable based on a random (dynamic) number, and append one of two variables (GT5K or LT5K) if it's greater than or less than 5000.

The JS Fiddle below contains my entire script--most of which is working, with the following exception:

```
var welcomePointsValue = jQuery('.welcomePointsValue').html();
var GT5K = '<p id="rcPoints">Redeem your points and save money today.</p>';
var LT5K = '<p id="rcPoints">Add bonus points to your room below and start earning more rewards.</p>';

if (welcomePointsValue < 5000) {
    //append var to ID if less than 5000 points
    jQuery('#posMsgWrapperCont').append(LT5K);
} else {
    //append var to ID if greater than 5000 points
    jQuery('#posMsgWrapperCont').append(GT5K);
}
```

I'm relatively green when it comes to using variables, so feel free to point out any issues I may be overlooking.

[View my JS Fiddle here...see line 37](http://jsfiddle.net/bkmills1/g5oot8tu/1/)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You should inject a proper numeric value (e.g. as a `data-pointsvalue` attribute) into your HTML in addition to the display version. The client code should not be dealing with converting formatted numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the number properly.

```
var welcomePointsValue = 
Number(jQuery('.welcomePointsValue > span').text().replace(/\D/g,""));
```

You can simplify your if to ternary if you want.

```
jQuery('#posMsgWrapperCont').append(welcomePointsValue > 5000 ? GTFK : LT5k);
```

P.S It will be more than good if you store it in `data-value` attribute and then use it like `.data('value')` to get it.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. Unfortunately, we're not using HTML5 yet, on this site. So I won't be able to use the data attribute.